# Geoserver Proxy Base URL doesn't take for Layer Previews

Tags: ubuntu, geoserver

I've configured a GeoServer for testing (2.19.2) on Ubuntu 20.04.  It's available on SSL via an Nginx reverse proxy and I can access the web interface at the expected address https://<www.expectedaddress.com>.  The Proxy Base URL is set to that same address in the GeoServer web interface settings.  It's my understanding that this is what needs to be configured so that all of the web interface functionality works properly.  However, it seems that the Layer Previews still point to 127.0.0.1:8080.
There may be other functionality that isn't working, but I've not discovered it yet.

What other configuration needs to be done in order make sure that https://<www.expectedaddress.com> is the Base Url applied?

Interestingly, the integrated GeoWeb Cache "Demo" page properly launches the OpenLayers previews, however.

Comment: It seems that some form buttons submit to http://127.0.0.1:8080 as well instead of to the Proxy Base Url address configured in the GeoServer Global settings page.   For example, attempting to log in as the admin.  At this point I don't think it has anything to do with Nginx or SSL.  CSRF is configured correctly, too.  What else besides that, whitelists, and the Proxy Base Url (and selecting "Use headers for Proxy Url) need to be set?  I've been trying to resolve this for a couple of days now with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so doing something that seems to go against all the other solutions I have seen fixed it for me. Simply removing the Proxy Base Url in the Geoserver global settings somehow worked. Everything I've tested seems to now be functional. Can't say that I understand why, but at this point, I'll take it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Be aware that removing the Proxy Base Url leads to publication of wrong Urls inside the service's capabilities documents (the Urls called by the reverse proxy server are used).

Comment: I'm facing similair issues and removing Proxy Base Url in the Geoserver global settings also worked for me. However I still would like to the correct url reported inside capabilities documents as pointed out by @DanielCalliess.. Did you eventually found a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was able to solve it by

- enabling *Use headers for Proxy URL* in the Global Settings,
- setting `${X-Forwarded-Proto}://${X-Forwarded-Host}${X-Forwarded-Path}` for the *Proxy Base URL*.

Then I went to the Edit Workspace page of the workspace in question and either

- Disabled the *Settings* or
- Enabled the *Settings* and entered the same proxy information as above into the appropriate fields.

After saving the changes I was able to open Layer Previews for layers of this workspace.